# Обновление JTable

Tags: jtable, gui, java

Здравствуйте.
Есть такая проблема: вывожу таблицу на фрейм, однако нужна возможность менять содержимое таблицы либо выводить новую.
Каким образом это лучше всего сделать?
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил так:

```
    table2.setBounds(280, 100, 170, 160);
    table2.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(buf2, columnNames));
    table2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(120);
    table2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(50);
```

Это мой случай, buf2 массив двумерный. После таких махинаций добавил табличку на фрейм, и всё заработало.